# Yii2 restrict user to manage (edit/delete) his own content

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to `Yii2` ( I have used `Yii` previously).
Is there any straight forward way in `Yii2` through which a user can be restricted to edit/delete his own content. for eg.

I have some posts in my system.Published posts can be seen by anyone.(only owner can view unpublished posts).

A post can be edit/delete by only content owner or Admin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the components provided by Yii2 for the authorization and control of access to the actions permitted to a user. To do this you should take a look at this:
[Yii user Authentication](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)